# What is this purple flowering serrated-leaf succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents, flowering

This is a waxy-leafed succulent with purple tube-shaped flowers.  I bought this plant at a yardsale in Virginia eight years ago.  The sellers have since moved away.

This propagated well by cuttings.  I did manage to keep them alive until last fall.  But they were never happy enough to flower again.

Does anyone out there know the name of this curious plant?  Or where I may find another?

[image: purple flowering succulent]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like Kalanchoe "Wendy".

https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/66915/Kalanchoe-Wendy/Details

Comment: Holy Cowbells!  The leaf shape made me think kalanchoe, but I had never seen that flower shape on a kalanchoe before.  That looks to be it!  Thank you!